# Use HTML inside vuetify v-text-field props

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'd like to use some html tags (sup, sub) inside vuetify's v-text-field label and suffix, but the below is not working. Any way to achieve that?

```
<v-text-field :label='mylabel' :suffix='mysuffix'></v-text-field>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    mylabel: 'A<sub>s</sub>',
    mysuffix: 'mm<sup>2</sup>',

  },
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/63t082p2/489/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look into [the source codes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/components/VTextField/VTextField.js#L31) for `v-text-field`, you will see it extends from `v-input`, then you will see [v-input has two slots](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/components/VInput/VInput.js#L254) named **prepend** and **append** (not sure why these two slots are not in the Vuetify Guide, you may want to [issue one feature request](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/issues)). You can use these two slots to implement the goal like below demo:

Or you want to try [another slot named `label`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/components/VInput/VInput.js#L217).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    mylabel: 'Test Label',
    mysuffix: 'Test suffix',
  },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<v-app id="app">
  <v-text-field :label='mylabel' :suffix='mysuffix'>
    <template slot="prepend"><i>Label: <sub>{{mylabel}}</sub></i></template>
    <template slot="append"><i>Suffix: <sub>{{mylabel}}</sub></i></template>
  </v-text-field>
</v-app>
```

Comment: Great thanks! I ended up using:

                                        <v-text-field >
                                            <template slot="label">
                                                <span v-html="mylabel"></span>
                                            </template>
                                            <template slot="append">
                                                <span v-html="mysuffix"></span>
                                            </template>
                                        </v-text-field>